# What is the limit for how many characters of metadata can be saved in the comments metadata of an MP4 file?

Tags: video, metadata

Suppose I have an MP4 file nd I want to add lots of info into the comments section.

What is the character limit for the comments section of MP4 metadata?

[image]

Comment: What research have you done on this? I'd imagine this is documented if there is a limit.

Comment: [Exiftool's Quicktime tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html) doesn't mention any character limit.  I did a quick test and exiftool was able to add a comment of 114,910 characters long.  No telling if there might be problems with other tools with a comment that big and I know that Windows has problems reading data from MP4s with a lot of data.